# Is Android's ViewPager and Flutter's PageView the same?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, dart

I have been developing apps in Android and have used viewPager many times. I want to implement a similar functionality in Flutter but the PageView widget provided by Flutter doesn't help. What's the best alternative for PageView which can help me obtain same functionality as ViewPager in Android. Basically, I am trying to implement [this view](https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager) in Flutter.